# Rspec, capybara getting started issues

Tags: ruby, rspec, site-prism

I have have started with simple example of Rspec,Capybara. I have come across few issues. This issues are probably because I have experience with `cucumber` and `page_object gem`, but here I am using `capybara` and `Site_prism gem`.

I have tried:
**my_example_spec.rb**
    require_relative 'Support/spec_helper'
    require_relative 'pages/login_page'

```
describe 'My behaviour'  do

  it 'should do something'do
    @login_page = LoginPage.new
    @login_page.load
    @login_page.login('autouser','password')
  end
end
```

and **login_page.rb**

```
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page

 set_url "/login"

  element :username, "input[id='username']"
  element :password, "input[id='password']"
  element :submit, "input[id='submit']"

  def login(username,password)
   @login_page.username.set username
   @login_page.password.set password
   @login_page.submit.click

  end

end
```

Issues are:

1. When I run `my_example_spec.rb` it gives error

   ```
   Testing started at ...
   Run options: include {:full_description=>/My\ behaviour\ should\ do\ something/}

   NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
   ./pages/login_page.rb:10:in `login'
   ./my_example_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   -e:1:in `load'
   -e:1:in `<main>'
   ```
2. Shouldn't it be `on(LoginPage).login (autouser, password)`. It should navigate to the page and run `login` method. It is how it works in `page_object gem` whats the equivalent of `site_prism gem`

Comment: it's saying `@login_page` in your `login` method is nil.  Where is that defined?

Comment: `login_page.rb` is class file of LoginPage shown above in code. Everything works fine it launches the browser, loads the URL (i.e. `@login_page.load`). If there was something wrong with the `login_page` class then `.load` wouldn't worked. So I think something is wrong with the way I am calling the `login`method. Also do yo have any idea on 2nd query?

Answer (score 1):

The login method in your LoginPage class should be

```
def login(username,password)
  username.set username
  password.set password
  submit.click
end
```

@login_page is not an instance variable of the LoginPage class so it is not accessible inside the class.  It's also not necessary inside the class since you're already inside the class.